# Time Data Type - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqldatatypes

I need to assign date & time to a record when the record is created , ( the time of creation )

I tried to use this statement but every time I recieve an error message :

```
'OrderDate' DATE DEFAULT (GETDATE()) NOT NULL,
```

when I tried to edit it visually , PHPMYSQL was showing a message that the the field data type was changed successfully , but it wasn't.

Bottom line ; I need to know the right data type / function to set a field's value as the time it was created .

thanks

Comment: you can use timestamp like **col_name TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**

Comment: I don't think he wants the OrderDate to change once the record is created, so `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` shouldn't be used.

Comment: @RossSmithII I agree. I have given only general syntax.

Comment: I tried this statement and it worked :

`'UB_Adding_Time' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`

is the value of this field changeable ??

@RossSmithII

Comment: The `UB_Adding_Time` field will have its initial value set to the current time, and whenever the record is updated, it will be updated to the current time as well (assuming it's the first `TIMESTAMP` field in the table)

Comment: and if I don't want to be changed ever again I should remove `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` Right ??

@RossSmithII

Comment: Just follow the answer below. Dhinakaran's answer is only going to confuse you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a field that automatically sets the date when the record is created use:

```
OrderDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

Before MySQL 5.6, if you require a `DATETIME` field type to auto-initialize, then you can define your `OrderDate` as

```
OrderDate DATETIME DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
```

and use a `TRIGGER` to assign the date:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS atable_insert_before;

DELIMITER //

CREATE
TRIGGER atable_insert_before
    BEFORE INSERT ON 
        atable
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF IFNULL(NEW.OrderDate, 0) <= 0
    THEN
        SET NEW.OrderDate = NOW();
    END IF;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

With MySQL 5.6, `DATETIME` fields can auto-initialize as `TIMESTAMP`s do now. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html